# Adding to HIMageList failing, cannot figure out why

Tags: c, windows, winapi, user-interface

I'm confused because I cannot establish why my ImageList_Add call is failing. I know it must be something that I am doing wrong with the Image or maybe I'm calling it wrong but I have no idea how I can go about fixing it :S Any help you can offer would be appreciated! :)

The code i'm using is below. I'm getting output on the console saying it couldn't add to the image list. From the docs,ImageList_Add will return an indice of where in the imagelist it managed to add the image so -1 is returned if it cant.

Which is all well and good but I cannot find anywhere why/what causes the add to fail!

The code may have memory leaks, though at the moment,ive spent almost a day trying to figure out various issues with this so I just want to get it to work!

```
    HIMAGELIST imageList = ImageList_Create(20,20,ILC_COLOR16,1,2 );
if (imageList == NULL)
{
    printf("Error creating imagelist - dlg_create_dropdown_menu. Returning NULL\n");
    return NULL;
}

HBITMAP currentImage = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL,"active_mdoe_icn.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
if (currentImage == NULL) 
{
   if (GetLastError()== 2) 
   {
       printf("File not found - dlg_create_dropdown_menu. Returning NULL.\n");
       return NULL;
   }
    printf("Error loading image from file - dlg_create_dropdown_menu. Returning NULL.\n");
    return NULL;
}
int imageIndex;
if ( (imageIndex = ImageList_Add(imageList,currentImage,NULL)) == -1 )
{
    printf("Error adding to the image list - dlg_create_dropdown_menu. Returning NULL.\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Thanks all, any help would be greatly received! :)

Could this be a problem with the actual image being corrupt? I've read about that in a few places.. Might just be my luck if i'm not doing anything daft :)

Comment: It's possibly that your image list uses `ILC_COLOR16` so it is 16 bit per pixel DIB but your bitmap after calling `LoadImage` will be a compatible bitmap, i.e. it matches your current display settings. So if they are not the same the add might fail. You could try using `ILC_COLORDDB` or you could make sure your bitmap format matches the image list and use `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` in the `LoadImage` call.

Comment: Try load another bitmap and see if your code work.  :-)

Comment: Yeah i'm going to try something with a simpler name like just active or something incase the _ are causing problems :) Thanks for all the advice, going to give a shot today :P

Comment: Still no luck, but i'm going to try a different widget and let you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much arguing with myself and windows I didnt figure out why the add was not working.

Instead of trying using the imagelist I just load in each image one at a time at work with it that way. Not sure why I thought using the image list was better :s

I was trying to load images into a dropdown menu I was creating but I found a better way of doing it. Which was using the MENUITEMINFO struct and specifying MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM_STRING as the two flags to fMask :) which mean I could have an image and an text in each menu item :)

Also image names with 0 underscores somehow makes it easier for windows to find lol

Anyways, hope this helped someone :)